# How to identify companies names in laws via regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

The Italian laws are officially published in the Gazzetta Ufficiale and I am trying to identify company names with the following regex:

```
azienda|societa'\s+([\w\s-]+) ha
```

which matches decently fragments such as:

```
Vista la domanda presentata in data 26 febbraio 2021 con  la  quale
la societa' Orpha-Devel Handels Und  Vertriebs  GMBH  ha  chiesto  la
riclassificazione dalla classe C(nn) alla  classe  H  del  medicinale
«Tresuvi» (treprostinil) relativamente alle confezioni aventi  A.I.C.
n. 049207032, 049207044, 049207018 e 049207020;
```

returning the string "Orpha-Devel Handels Und  Vertriebs  GMBH  " in the matching group.In this case to be "perfect" I just want the trailing blanks (usually one or two) to not be included in the returned matching group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:azienda|societa)'\s+(\w+(?:[\s-]+\w+)*)\s+ha
(?:azienda|societa)'\s+(.*?)\s+ha
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/pgn9CJ/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/pgn9CJ/2).

Note that you should group `azienda` and `societa` or, the capturing group will only match with `societa`, but not `azienda`.

*Details*:

- `(?:azienda|societa)` - either `azienda` or `societa`
- `'` - a `'` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:[\s-]+\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces/hyphen chars and then one or more word chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `ha` - a `ha` string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Your pattern works well with a minor modification (the ' after societa is used instead of the accented à) -> (?:azienda|societa')\s+(.*?)\s+ha
Now I just need to understand how to include potential Line breaks such as per the following example:
societa'   Mundipharma (linefeed)
Pharmaceuticals S.r.l. ha (linefeed)
which should capture Mundipharma Pharmaceuticals S.r.l.

Comment: @RobertAlexander With `(?:azienda|societa)'\s+([\w\W]*?)\s+ha`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgn9CJ/4).

Comment: Wow, thanks learning a lot studying your examples :) Thanks. In this latter regex is there a way NOT to include the LF in the captured group?

Comment: @RobertAlexander No, it is not possible.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, will filter the returned string programmatically (eliminate LF, reduce multiple spaces to single, uppercase all)